# Street Light Arrangement Method

Tags: civil-engineering, highway-engineering, lighting, roadway

Hello I am a high school student and I am curious about how street light is arranged along the road. Is there government laws to install street light on the road or is the arangement of the street light that is the most efficient to its road? If it is, how are the lights arrangement? Is it by some sort of software?

Comment: You don't say what country you are talking about, but in the UK there are several national  standards documents relating to street lighting. BS 5489-1, Code of Practice for the Design of Road Lighting, would be a good starting point.

Comment: Is this a homework question, because if so we prefer to help only after you've done some research on your own.   One hint: it can't be software, since street lights have been in existence for over a hundred years prior to the first mechanical computers.

Comment: "it can't be software" Why not? I doesn't make any sense to say "something has been done without computers for hundreds of years, therefore we don't use computers to do it now."

Comment: It may not necessarily *require* software, but as an employee of one of the larger lighting manufacturers in North America I can assure you that these days software is certainly used to calculate the optimum placement of street lighting (and other lighting, both indoor and outdoor). When you can feed in the photometric pattern of your luminair with its various lense options, play with mounting heights, etc, etc and see the calculated results all on your PC why would you not do this?

Comment: I aologoze that I did not mention i am a student from south korea and trying to start reseaech on finding optimum solution for finding street light arrangement on complicated roads. i could not find any documents about so i am leaving question.

Comment: can you please tell me the name of the software used to design structure? :D

Answer (score 1):

Street lights are installed in order to provide a minimum lighting level along the roadway. Some municipalities or states or countries may have minimum lighting standards, but these often vary depending on the context (i.e. rural, urban, intersections).

For certain situations, such as lighting for mid-block or pedestrian crossings, there may be additional requirements beyond merely lighting level. Putting the lights so they illuminate the front of a pedestrian in a crosswalk provides better visibility than placing the lights overhead or behind the pedestrians, so some newer standards may require lighting be placed accordingly so they are in front of the crosswalk on the approach legs to a crosswalk or intersection.